# Compare multiple cells for minimum value with criteria

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a Google Spreadsheet for which I need to solve the following (I have tried using the MINIFS function, but it did not end well):

```
A1: "0" 
B1: "100" 
C1: "1" 
D1: "150" 
E1: "1" 
F1: "101"
```

A1, C1 and E1 represent stock, B1, D1 and F1 product ID.

In G1: cell I need to compare B1:D1:F1 and list the minimum, only if A1:C1:E1 value is not ==0
The correct content in this case would be G1:"101".

Could you help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take:

```
=IF(AND(A2>0; 
        C2>0; 
        E2>0); MIN({B2; D2; F2}); "out")
```


[image]

fix for blank row:

```
=IF(({A5; B5; C5; D5; E5; F5}<>""); IF(AND(A5>0;
                                           C5>0;
                                           E5>0); MIN({B5; D5; F5}); "out"); )
```


[image]